# How to run Specflow tests written in C# using Docker and xUnit properly?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, specflow

I am trying to run my Specflow tests using Docker. I have a project which contains .feature files written in Gherkin. When I'm trying to run the tests using my Rider IDE, everything is working correctly. When I'm running the docker image locally, also everything is fine. The problem is starting on the remote pipelines (using the GitHub Actions). When I am starting the container with the tests, the image is built and the the whole execution stops at this moment:

```
/src/MyProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MyProject.dll
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.3+1b45f5407b (64-bit .NET Core 3.1.22)
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.91]   Discovering: MyProject
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.03]   Discovered:  MyProject
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.03]   Starting:    MyProject
-> Loading plugin /src/MyProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/LivingDoc.SpecFlowPlugin.dll
-> Loading plugin /src/MyProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/TechTalk.SpecFlow.xUnit.SpecFlowPlugin.dll
-> Loading plugin /src/MyProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MyProject.dll
-> Missing [assembly:RuntimePlugin] attribute in MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Please check https://go.specflow.org/doc-plugins for details.
-> Using default config
```

Then it's suspended forever and is running, but nothing really happens then. This is the problem only in the remote pipeline executor.
This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY "solution.sln" .
COPY "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" ./MyProject/

RUN dotnet restore "solution.sln"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build --no-restore "solution.sln" -c Release
CMD dotnet test "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c Release -l "trx;LogFileName=/src/results/testresults.trx" -l "Console;Verbosity=Detailed"
```

Any ideas what could be wrong in here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `Missing [assembly:RuntimePlugin] attribute in MyProject` -- this seems to be the problem.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Thanks for your interest, I've noticed that before, but this is not the case in here :/ I've updated the version of the package and for now it's not telling anything about the missing package but still is being suspended on the same line :/

Comment: What normally comes after `Using default config`? That is probably the thing that gets hung up.